# Use relative paths to link library file

Tags: xcode

My xcode project links to the TestFlight library (libTestFlight.a) and the project is also under git (locally) which I then push up to bitbucket.

I then pull the project down to my macbook pro.  However the first build fails because its trying to find the libTestFlight.a file using a path that is relative to my iMac.  I can change the project settings and all is OK, but I'd like to avoid this happening on every refresh between machines.

I can't seem to find a way to make the linker find the file relative to the xcode project directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your bundle contains the static library, then in `Build Settings` you can put the value

```
"$SOURCE_ROOT"
```

No matter which machine your code runs in, it will always point to the correct root folder.

The same can be given for `Header Search Paths`.

Comment: Thanks, that did it (although I had to look in the actual project file to see the change because xcode kept the full path name in the ide)